# Turtle module has no attribute color?

Tags: python, python-3.2, turtle-graphics

When I try to run the first piece of sample code from the [Python documentation on `turtle`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/turtle.html#module-turtle):

```
from turtle import *
color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

I get a `NameError`:

> NameError: name 'color' is not defined

Tweaking the `import` and manually specifying the module doesn't work either:

```
import turtle
turtle.color('red', 'yellow')
turtle.begin_fill()
while True:
    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.left(170)
    if abs(turtle.pos()) < 1:
        break
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.done()
```

I am using Python v3.2.3, which clearly contains [`turtle.color`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/turtle.html#turtle.color), per the documentation. Python is installed with `tkinter` support as well, because `import tkinter` works as well.

The full trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path name that contains no spaces>/turtle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from turtle import *
  File "<path name that contains no spaces>\turtle.py", line 2, in <module>
    color('red', 'yellow')
NameError: name 'color' is not defined
```

How odd. If I enter the shell, either the command line or IDLE, and enter the commands one at a time:

```
>>> from turtle import *
>>> color('red', 'yellow')
```

there isn't a problem. It's only when I open a new window in IDLE, enter all of the commands, and run the script.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. What OS are you running this on? Also can you give us the full trace? Thanks!

Comment: @Trufa I'm running this on Windows 7 x64. I'll add the full trace.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You named your file "turtle.py" so when you `import turtle`, you are importing your own file instead of the stdlib module.  Change the name of your program, and delete all the .pyc files in that directory.